# Audio Signal Normalization

Tags: c++, normalization, wav, audio-streaming

I have a conceptual question about how digital audio is stored both as signed and unsigned int values.

My understanding is this (let's take 16bit audio stored as signed integers):

- Signal range is -32768 to 32767
- 0 represents the midpoint of the signal; so when there is no sound, your signal should sit at 0

So if you want to normalize this signal to say the 0-1 range, your signal midpoint would be 0.5

When I process 16bit WAV files, this is exactly what I see which makes normalization straightforward.

The issue is when I play 8bit signed audio, say from 'Stereo Mix' in Windows, I get a value of -128 instead of 0 when there is no sound coming in. The signal otherwise does have the -128 to 127 range.

- Is my assumption correct about the midpoint being 0 for signed integers?
- If not, what is the correct midpoint and why are things different between 8bit and 16bit signed integer audio?
- What would be the range and midpoint for unsigned 8bit integers for example? 0 to 255 with 128 as the midpoint?

This is the QT code adapted from an example that I use to figure out audio format and to read incoming data:

```
AudioIODevice::AudioIODevice(QObject *parent, const QAudioFormat &deviceFormat) :
    QIODevice(parent),
    format(deviceFormat)
{
   int sampleSize = format.sampleSize();
   switch (format.sampleType())
   {
    case QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt:
       minValue = 0.0f;
       maxValue = static_cast<float>(std::pow(2,sampleSize) - 1);
       break;
    case QAudioFormat::SignedInt:
       minValue = static_cast<float>((std::pow(2,sampleSize)/2) * (-1));
       maxValue = static_cast<float>((std::pow(2,sampleSize)/2) - 1);
       break;  
   case QAudioFormat::Float:
        break;
    default:
       break;
   }
}

qint64 AudioIODevice::writeData(const char *data, qint64 len)
{
    unsigned int sampleBytes = format.sampleSize() / 8;                 //Number of bytes for each interleaved channel sample
    unsigned int combSampleBytes = format.channelCount() * sampleBytes; //Number of bytes for all channel samples
    unsigned int numSamples = len / combSampleBytes;                    //Total number of samples

    if(format.sampleSize() % 8 != 0 || len % sampleBytes != 0)
        return -1;

    //Prepare our output buffer
    buffer.clear();
    buffer.resize(numSamples,0);

    const unsigned char* uData = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(data);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numSamples; i++)
    {        
        float monoValue = minValue;
        float value = minValue;

        //Process data for all interleaved samples
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < format.channelCount(); j++)
        {
            switch (format.sampleType())
            {
                case QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt:
                switch(format.sampleSize())
                {
                    case 8:
                    value = *reinterpret_cast<const quint8*>(uData);
                    break;
                    case 16:
                    value = (format.byteOrder()==QAudioFormat::LittleEndian)?
                                (qFromLittleEndian<quint16>(*reinterpret_cast<const quint16*>(uData))):
                                (qFromBigEndian<quint16>(*reinterpret_cast<const quint16*>(uData)));
                    break;
                    case 32:
                    value = (format.byteOrder()==QAudioFormat::LittleEndian)?
                                (qFromLittleEndian<quint32>(*reinterpret_cast<const quint32*>(uData))):
                                (qFromBigEndian<quint32>(*reinterpret_cast<const quint32*>(uData)));
                    break;
                    default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
                case QAudioFormat::SignedInt:
                switch(format.sampleSize())
                {
                    case 8:
                    value = *reinterpret_cast<const qint8*>(uData);
                    break;
                    case 16:
                    value = (format.byteOrder()==QAudioFormat::LittleEndian)?
                                (qFromLittleEndian<qint16>(*reinterpret_cast<const qint16*>(uData))):
                                (qFromBigEndian<qint16>(*reinterpret_cast<const qint16*>(uData)));
                    break;
                    case 32:
                    value = (format.byteOrder()==QAudioFormat::LittleEndian)?
                                (qFromLittleEndian<qint32>(*reinterpret_cast<const qint32*>(uData))):
                                (qFromBigEndian<qint32>(*reinterpret_cast<const qint32*>(uData)));
                    break;
                    default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
                case QAudioFormat::Float:
                break;
                default:
                break;
            }
            monoValue = std::max(value,monoValue);
            uData += sampleBytes; //Get data for the next sample
        }
        buffer[i] = (monoValue - minValue) / (maxValue - minValue);    //Normalize the value to [0-1]

    }
    emit bufferReady();
    return len;
}
```

The AudioIODevice class inherits QT's [QIODevice](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html) which is used to read low level data.

Comment: Testing via Audacity, there is no option for signed 8-bit linear PCM for the Windows WAV format. When exporting in other uncompressed formats (e.g. AIFF), the behaviour is exactly as expected (0 as mid-point for signed 8bit Linear PCM). Maybe you are facing some undefined behaviour from the Stereo Mix?

Comment: Could you post some code ? How did you find that -128 silent offset, because that seems very strainge. 8-bit sound is as far as I know unsgned, with a midpoint at 128 which actually represents a value of 0 (zero) for a signed byte.. OR -128, for that matter. But.. we're talking sound.. the correct midpoint should *actually* be where your input sais it is. For some devices operating in 16 or 32 bits, there will be a small DC offset when recording A/D in real life.

Comment: What is the file type & what does your research show is its format?

Comment: A constant DC signal would be silent no matter its value.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please see [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to learn to use @x to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter x re a comment. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. PS Still no research about the file type.

Comment: Thanks guys! 'Stereo Mix' and 'Microphone Array' both act the same way and they function normally. I edited my question and added the code I use to read the audio data. The QAudioFormat class doesn't give any information about where the audio midpoint should be, it only tells you things like sample rate / size / type. I'm going to try this code on a different machine to see if I see the same results. The file type that I used is from the NSynth dataset the format of which is: 16-bit PCM WAV and that's consistent with what I get when I read data from them.

Comment: See my last comment. See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to learn to use @  to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter or 1 of certain other users about a comment. (Posters & followers aways get notified.) (Only followers got notified of your last comment.)

Answer (score 0):

After a few months of searching for an definitive answer to this topic, I've reached the conclusion that my original assumption would be correct as @amiasato also hinted. This page describes how to determine the midpoint of a standard PCM audio signal:

https://gist.github.com/endolith/e8597a58bcd11a6462f33fa8eb75c43d

For example an 8-bit signed PCM signal has these ranges:

Min: -128
Max: 128
Midpoint: 0

As to why the signal I'm getting from my soundcard sits at -128 when there is no sound, I'm going to assume that this is related to a driver problem or could be that this particular piece of hardware does not follow the PCM standard.

If anyone has any further input, please feel free to add it.